# componentRestrictions is not working with placeId in reverse Geocoding in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

When I first implemented google maps in my project, It was working fine but suddenly it stops working and starting giving error as below.

**InvalidValueError: cannot set both placeId and componentRestrictions**

When I removed **componentRestrictions** option then It working fine.

Is there any change in google maps api ?

See My below Code

```
// Initialize the map.
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.72, lng: -73.96}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

// This function is called when the user clicks the UI button requesting
// a reverse geocode.
function geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var placeId = document.getElementById('place-id').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
  'placeId': placeId,
   componentRestrictions: {
         country: 'USA'  
     }
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoz1eo8v/1/) link.

Comment: A placeId specifies a unique place in the world, it doesn't make sense to use both a placeId and component restrictions.  (I wouldn't be surprised if that is a change, the API is always changing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I actually found the reason why it got stopped working on the same day.

But now I am sharing, Unintentionally I have used google map Api Experimental version as following below, which got upgraded by google time to time.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**yourapikey**&v=3.exp&libraries=places

But now I have used frozen version of google map api which is **v=3.27**

You can find google map api version from the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

and You can find google map api Release Notes from the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases